# Reverse features of Select by Location for "Have their center in"?

Tags: arcgis-pro, select-by-location

I have a feature class of large boundary polygons and a feature class of small polygons. Some of these small polygons the boundary of two larger polygons by a very small amount. I'm trying to accomplish the following workflow but running into issues:

1. Select a small polygon
2. Select the large polygon that the smaller polygon is mostly within but has a very small amount crossing the boundary to two polygons.

The Select by Location tool has the option for "Have their Center in" which is...mostly what I want but with the features reversed. I want to select the polygon that contains the centroid/center of the selected feature/polygon. Is there a way to do this without running other tools first? I can't seem to get the feature that contains the center of another feature.

Is there another way to select a single large polygon when the input is a small, single polygon that crosses the boundary of two of the larger polygons by only by a very small area?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing what you want to select

Comment: Here's a picture of what I was trying to select. https://imgur.com/a/slZzalr

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the answer online easily so hopefully this simple answer helps someone in the far future. You can use an INTERSECT with a negative number to cut off areas outside a certain distance, somewhat like using a reverse buffer to select by.